# "find" command with a variable directory

Tags: bash, variables, find

I'm trying to list the files in a directory that is given by the variable `DIR`. My code looks like this so far:

```
for i in `find $DIR -name "*.txt"
```

The variable `DIR` is already defined. I'm not sure what the syntax is here.

Comment: Why not `ls "$DIR"`?

Comment: I need to also include the .txt part because I'm only looking in .txt files.

Comment: Are you interested in the files in sub-directories of `$DIR`, or only in `$DIR` itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls "${DIR}/*.txt"
```

or

```
find "${DIR}" -name "*.txt"
```

should do the trick. The first one only lists `*.txt` files in the directory itself, the second one also `*.txt` files in subdirectories.

Comment: Dang it, I thought I gave a comprehensive answer, and forgot the `ls ${DIR}/*.txt`...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to execute a given action on all files with extension "txt" under `$DIR` and/or its subdirs. As usual there are different solutions.

This one:

```
$ for i in $(find "$DIR" -name \*.txt) ; do echo "Do something with ${i}" ; done
```

**won't work** if file path (either the file itself or one subdirectory) contains spaces.

But you can use this:

```
$ find "$DIR" -type f -name \*.txt | while read i ; do echo "Do something with ${i}" ; done
```

or this:

```
$ find "$DIR" -type f -name \*.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} echo "Do something with {}"
```

or this:

```
$ find "$DIR" -type f -name \*.txt -exec echo "Do something with {}" \;
```

or... 100 additional solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want.

```
find $DIR -name "*.txt" -print
```

will list all the files that end with `.txt` and are located in `$DIR` or its subdirectories. You can omit the `-print` as that is the default behaviour anyway.

If you have a simple thing you want to do with this file, you can use `find`'s `-exec` function:

```
find $DIR -name "*.txt" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
for f in `find $DIR -name "*.txt"`; do
    wc -l $f
    mv $f /some/other/dir/
fi
```

**note**: as @mauro helpfully pointed out, this will not work if the `DIR` or the file names contain spaces.

Cheers

Comment: Loop solution won't work if file path contains one or more spaces.

Comment: You are right. I never use spaces in file or directory names, so I didn't consider it. I added a note. (Though whether that was worth a down vote I don't know).